# Automatic update of displayed data from localStorage using AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, local-storage, alpine.js

I'm trying to use AlpineJS to update the displayed data from `localStorage` every time I click a button.

I have two buttons that use `setItem` to update the value in localStorage.

This all works, but I can't figure out how to use AlpineJS to update the displayed data (using `getItem`) when the button is clicked.

When the button is clicked, the value in `localStorage` does change, but I have to reload the page to update the data on FE.

Could someone give me some advice on how to solve this using AlpineJS?

## CodePen

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/kuldas/pen/PoeZaKx)

I'm new to AlpineJS and I've tried the documentation, but I really don't know how to grasp it.

Thank you in advance for any tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not working because `localStorage` is not reactive, so you need a page reload to see the mutated state. Everything you do on the frontend should utilize reactive Alpine.js variables and use a watcher to sync the state of these variables with the `localStorage`. Furthermore Alpine.js provides a [`localStorage` plugin](https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/persist), so you don't even have to sync them manually just put a `$persist()` to the respective variables:

```
<!-- Alpine Plugins -->
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/@alpinejs/persist@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
 
<!-- Alpine Core -->
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ name: $persist('') }">
  <button @click="name = 'Link'">Set name to Link</button>
  <button @click="name = 'Zelda'">Set name to Zelda</button>
  <div x-text='`Selected name: ${name}`'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Dauros,
thank you very much for your reply. I feel a bit embarrassed because I read in the documentation about the persist plugin, but I didn't really understand how to use it.

Now I understand and I'm a bit smarter now :D